# package.json: adding multiple scripts into one script

Tags: package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "vue-cli-service ftpdeploy --genHist --diffFileOnly --ftpCfgPath /ftpdeploy/ --ftpHistPath /ftpdeploy/",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve && deploy",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
```

I am trying to automatically deploy via ftp code when ever vue serve is ran.

Is this the correct syntax as I am getting errors, what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"scripts": {
"deploy": "vue-cli-service ftpdeploy --genHist --diffFileOnly --ftpCfgPath /ftpdeploy/ --ftpHistPath /ftpdeploy/",
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve && **npm run** deploy",
"build": "vue-cli-service build"
},